# macOS change the resolution of Blender window not the render resolution

Tags: osx, resolution

On macOS with 4k display blender always renders double pixels as the resolution you choose in display setting of macOS. For example if I choose 1920x1080 hidpi scaling in the display setting the blender will render 3840x2160 which is double of 1920x1080.
[image]
[image]

If I choose 2560x1440 in display setting blender will render 5120x2880 then which is even more pixels my 4k monitor has. This will make blender quite lag on heavy scenes.
[image]
[image]
Is it possible to make Blender render the same resolution as my display setting? I checked some game on Apple Arcade can do that. For example the game Stitch. If I change my display resolution to 1920x1080 then it only renders 1920x1080.

Comment: do you mean in the viewport?

Comment: yes, in the viewport